# Reactive Linq Observable doesn't notify when an event is fired

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive, observable

I am trying to get my head around the Observable pattern and basically fix an issue on an existing code that doesn't notify when an event is fired.

The event that I am observing is the `ResizeGroupItemEnded` defined as:

```
public event EventHandler<StGroupItemsModified> ResizeGroupItemEnded
```

So, the setup of the pattern is as follows:

```
private readonly IDisposable _groupUpdates;
private static readonly TimeSpan UpdateThrottle = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
...
_groupUpdates = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<StGroupItemsModified>, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(e => groupUICtrl.ResizeGroupItemEnded += e, e => groupUICtrl.ResizeGroupItemEnded -= e)
                          .Throttle(UpdateThrottle)
                          .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
                          .Subscribe(x => RefreshVLines());
...
public void Dispose()
{
...
}

private void RefreshVLines()
{
  // We should be notified here when groupUICtrl.ResizeGroupItemEnded triggers
}
```

Why is `RefreshVLinesStep()` not called when `groupUICtrl.ResizeGroupItemEnded` is triggered? Any ideas please?

Comment: This might be just a typo - but you're subscribing to `RefreshVLines()` & not `RefreshVLinesStep()`. Can you confirm if this is a typo or not?

Comment: Yes true it was a typo. Thanks for observing that

Comment: There's nothing in the code that you've shown that explains what's going on. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes thats the full code which is shows where the registration of the Observable pattern takes place.

Comment: Have you tried subscribing directly to the FromEventPattern (to check that this event is actually fired), and then moving the subscription to after the throttle (to see if they're happening faster than every 300ms) and also checking the value passed as SynchronizationContext.Current to see if it's what you expect?

Comment: Is the Throttle really needed in an Observable pattern? I will try to remove it and see if it fixes the issue. As I explained i am not at all familiar with the Reactive Linq Observable...

Comment: Throttle is used when you expect a flood of events followed by a pause, and you only want to respond to the last event before the pause (e.g. typing in a search box).

Comment: @marklam: I have subscribed directly to the groupUICtrl.ResizeGroupItemEnded and it is notified. So the event is firing. I also tried to remove the throttle and it made no difference. Will check your other suggestions..

Comment: @Nostradamus - The [mcve] means you need to provide code that we can run that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: My guess (wouldn't be a guess if your code was complete) is that your FromEventPattern code is broken. It's very easy to get misled because many overloads are using reflection and aren't providing compile-feedback. In your case does `StGroupItemsModified` extend `PropertyChangedEventArgs` or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong generic arguments.
Your code actually throws `System.ArgumentException` exception

You should change `PropertyChangedEventArgs` to actual event args, which are `StGroupItemsModified`

```
_groupUpdates = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<StGroupItemsModified>, StGroupItemsModified>(e => groupUICtrl.ResizeGroupItemEnded += e, e => groupUICtrl.ResizeGroupItemEnded -= e)
                          .Throttle(UpdateThrottle)
                          .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
                          .Subscribe(x => RefreshVLines());
```

Or you could simplify it by using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229705(v=vs.103).aspx)

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<StGroupItemsModified>(...)
```